# android jave how to retrieve an image of the incoming call screen

Tags: android

Can i put on my activity the incoming call screen as a background?
The picture of the screen of how it looks like when there's a call.
Every phone is different with its screen, thats way im looking for a way
to retrieve it from the phones system if it possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android jave how to retrieve an image of the incoming call screen

This is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices. You cannot capture screenshots programmatically, for obvious privacy and security reasons.